# Virtualisation in a managed/one-app environment

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization

So, I'm very interested in running my testing machines and servers virtually and considered vmware, VirtualBox, VirtualPC and qemu. From all those solutions, I like qemu and VirtualBox most, but both of them lack of a uniformed, managed interface to handle the machines.

There was vmware Server a few years ago, which was also free and somehow the perfect solution for me. But it's now unsupported and deprecated. Is there any free follow-up or alternative? I don't want to run x players (vmware/virtualbox or whatever) in their own window.

I know there's also vmware ESX, but this requires a very strict hardware constellation such as plain intel products (chipset, network adapter) etc.

Comment: Have you seen the virt-manager?

Answer (score 0):

I still use VMWare server on one PC, and it's fine for my needs, but those revolve around running legacy OS (Windows XP, Centos 5 in my case) rather than running an up-to-date client OS.  I believe that Windows 7 would be OK in VMWare server, but Windows 8 would probably not run.

If you're planning on upgrading your host OS to Windows 8, you may want to consider Hyper-V as your virtualization solution, since that is provided free of charge with the OS.

Answer (score 0):

`I don't want to run x players (vmware/virtualbox or whatever) in their own window.`

You can hold `shift` down when starting a VM in VirtualBox to start it "headless". There is also an option under the start button to start headless.

To connect use SSH, RDP or other remote access software. VirtualBox also has a `Remote Display` option to use RDP to connect directly to the console (emulating physical keyboard/mouse). I would make sure a firewall is enabled and access it via SSH tunnels.

You can make scripts that use the `VBoxManage` command to start/stop/configure VMs and run those over SSH.